How to Relate Classe and Exam Through Subject in Laravel?
Hello Laravel community,
I’m currently working on a Laravel application where I have the following models and relationships:
Classe: A Classe has many Subjects.
Subject: Each Subject has many Exams through a pivot table exam_subject.
Exam: An Exam can have multiple Subjects.
I want to define a relationship in Laravel that allows me to fetch all Classes associated with a given Exam through the Subject model.
I defined a hasManyThrough relationship, but it doesn’t seem to fit this many-to-many scenario with the pivot table involved.
Could someone help me set up the proper relationship or query to achieve this?
Thank you in advance for your help!

you can simply read the docs https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many
